# How can I still onChange data by scanning when hide the virtual keyboard is hide (inputMode=none) in reactjs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, keyboard

I faced an issue related with input in reactjs.
I want to hide virtual keyboard when input is focus, I am using **inputMode = "none"** or add **readOnly** for this input.

But I cannot change any data of input by using **onPressEnter**.

```
 <Input
      type="text"
      value={scanBox}
      onPaste={handlePaste}
      placeholder="Paste and press Enter"
      ref={boxInputRef}
      onChange={(e: any) => setScanBox((e?.target?.value).toUpperCase())}
      inputMode="none"
      onFocus={handleInputFocus}
      onPressEnter={() => handleScanBox(scanBox)}
      onBlur={handleInputBlur}
    />
```

[My codesandbox](https://kzjsvl.csb.app/)
Do any ways to hide virtual keyboard still scanning data of this input?

Thank you so much!